# How to check if certain user has made database items using jsp view

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a database table called bookings, and what i'm trying to do but couldn't find so far, is to check with if-else, if there are bookings made by certain user, and display them in a table.

[image]

So i'm looking for something like this:

(semi-pseudo code below)

```
<c:when test="${bookings.where(booking.userId == currentUserId) > 0}">
   display table with those items...
</c:when>
```

so this would get me all the table items made by that user

How can i test this in a jsp view page?

Thanks in advance.

PS: displaying the items is not a problem, i can at least do that on my own :)

**EDIT backend part** :

```
@GetMapping("/bookings")
    public String getAllBookings(Model model) {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        User user = userService.findByUsername(userDetail.getUsername());
        int currentUserId = user.getId();

        List<Booking> bookings = bookingService.getAllBookings();
        model.addAttribute("bookings", bookings);

        model.addAttribute("currentUserId", currentUserId);
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", getPrincipal());

        return "booking-list";
    }
```

Comment: Post full back-end code plz. What is bookings? Why where statement here?

Comment: @Loc dont want to use backend for this, i want to do this in jsp view page, with if and else, if user has made bookings show them, else display some message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you probably should do this on backend and just pass filtered list, but for the jsp approach you can use `forEach`.

Example:

```
<c:forEach items="${bookings}" var="booking">
    <c:if test="${booking.userId == currentUserId}">
       ...
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

**Edit: question updated**

To filter bookings in the backend you could use `Stream API`:

```
List<Booking> bookings = bookingService.getAllBookings().stream()
        .filter(b -> b.getUserId() == currentUserId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
model.addAttribute("bookings", bookings);
```

**Edit 2.0:**

Actually you shouldn't even filter them in java. Since you take the data from database, you should implement `getBookingsForUserId()` and use `WHERE` clause to filter them.

Comment: Ok, how to filter them in my controller ? I`ll post my backend part for the list in the question.

Comment: Actually, I've just been enlightened and updated the answer with Edit 2.0 ;)